# Naming the action of putting legs apart sideways when walking/climbing

Tags: phrase-requests

When one climbs a mountain path, one often takes care to put one foot more to the left, the other more to the right, with a distance between them.

What os the right English terms for this? "Spreading one's legs" normally applies to sitting or lying down, not to walking? So how do I call this one?

Comment: taking wider steps? Perhaps?

Comment: Waddling? Walking bow-legged / pigeon-toed?

Comment: take zig-zag steps

Comment: In cross-country skiing there's the herringbone for climbing uphill \  /.  See also "triangular stance".

Answer (score 1):

I think 'straddle' is the correct verb.

The OED defines it as "1.1 Place (one's legs) wide apart.
‘he shifted his legs, straddling them to keep his balance’"

Comment: That definition is not from the OED (i.e. oed.com), it's from ODO (en.oxforddictionaries.com).

Answer (score 0):

**akimbo**  [TFD](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/akimbo)

> Adj   akimbo - (used of arms and/or legs) bent outward with the joint away
>   from the body

[image: climber] here 2 legs and one arm!

Used here: [google books](https://books.google.com/books?id=Tt0-o0IQopkC&lpg=PA400&ots=GWRcrhvWxe&dq=climbing%20with%20legs%20akimbo&pg=PA400#v=onepage&q=climbing%20with%20legs%20akimbo&f=false)

> A climber, arms raised, **legs akimbo**, is caught leaping from one
>   pinnacle to an adjacent one while below, a quaint village nestles
>   against a fjord.

Answer (score 0):

As a seasoned mountain hiker / sailor, I can tell you that some of us enjoy using the term [**sea legs**](https://www.mountainproject.com/forum/topic/106592416/20092010-colorado-ice-conditions?page=7#ForumMessage-106637985) with reference to hiking rough land trails. It's all very tongue-in-cheek humor of the kind that is easily understood and appreciated by anyone who engages in both sports, and by most mountaineers even if they don't go near the water:

- Listen people, you'll need to use your **sea legs** up ahead. It's very rough terrain, so keep your balance by setting your feet a little further apart than usual, and step carefully.

> Anyone got updates on the Big Thompson?? Looking to head out there maybe early this week....Need to warmup and get my **sea legs** back :)